# Error showing after `ng serve` command on Angular 11

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, serve, angular11

I'm facing a problem to work with *Angular 11.* After installing using ubuntu terminal created a project by `ng new [project-name]` command. And command over it by `ng serve` to run by **ubuntu terminal**. but it shows an error. Why this problem and how can it be solved?

The error like as follows...

[image]

Comment: Can you include what commands you did to install Angular?

Comment: I used this command to install angular npm install @angular/cli -g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue by this conversation.

[image]

Thanks to all for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

From issue comment from angular repository https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29960#issuecomment-484420080

Recovering from that is impossible. You will need to delete the **node_modules** folder and run `npm install` again to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I installed Angular 11 version but when run command "ng serve" I got the errors as displaying in above screenshot.

Then, I tried all the things with Window OS and I didn't get any error. I just took the code from Window system to Ubuntu and then tried to run and now I's working fine.